# CSS: Infinitely looping animation doesn't interpolate between the first and last keyframes

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly certain I'm noticing this right and I can't seem to find a proper solution anywhere. I have a CSS animation that's meant to loop infinitely, it already works but has a problem.

```
// CSS
@keyframes myanim {
    0% { transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg); }
    25% { transform: translate(5px, 5px) rotate(1deg) skewX(1deg); }
    50% { transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0eg) skewX(0deg); }
    75% { transform: translate(-5px, -5px) rotate(-1deg) skewX(-1deg); }
    100% { transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg); }
}

// JS
element.style.animation = "myanim " + mytimer + "s infinite";
```

Keyframe interpolation doesn't seem to work around the seams. Between points 0% and 100% there's no interpolation: When the animation just started or is approaching the end each iteration, it slows down / sets into place / speeds up instead of maintaining its constant rhythm like between the other keyframes. It it possible to tell the browser to interpret all keyframes in a circular manner for the loop to work as intended?

Comment: Using `linear` instead of `ease` improves the problem: No more slowing down or speeding up at least. But I still can't solve the lack of interpolation, the animation makes a sharp turn the moment it reaches each keyframe instead of creating a circular curve between all points. Perhaps this is the limitation of what CSS can do, might leave it like that if a better solution isn't suggested.

Answer (score 0):

@ MirceaKitsune is right you need to use the linear animation property.
I tried out the animation and it works, here is the fiddle:

```css
.animated-heading {
  animation: linear myanim 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes myanim {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
  }
  12.5% {
    transform: translate(2.5px, 2.5px) rotate(0.5deg) skewX(0.5deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(5px, 5px) rotate(1deg) skewX(1deg);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: translate(2.5px, 2.5px) rotate(0.5deg) skewX(0.5deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0eg) skewX(0deg);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg) skewX(-0.5deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-5px, -5px) rotate(-1deg) skewX(-1deg);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: translate(-2.5px, -2.5px) rotate(-0.5deg) skewX(-0.5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg) skewX(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="animated-heading">animated-heading</h1>
```